# Задача на подсчет количества палиндромов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Условие задачи: "Назовем число палиндромом, если оно не меняется при перестановке его цифр в обратном порядке. Напишите программу, которая по заданному числу K выводит количество натуральных палиндромов, не превосходящих K."

Вот как выглядит моё решение:

```
K = int(input())
countNumber = 0
a = 0
flip = 0
Number = 0
countFlip = 0


while countNumber <= K:
    countNumber += 1
    Number = countNumber
    while Number > 0:
        a = Number % 10
        Number = Number // 10
        flip = flip * 10 + a
    if countNumber == flip:
       countFlip += 1

print(countFlip)
```

По моей логике код должен работать следующим образом:

- Вводятся числа K, счетчик, который завершит работу цикла; переменные a, Number и flip для "переворота" числа; и счетчик countFlip для подсчета палиндромов.
- счетчик countNumber будет увеличиваться до тех пор, пока не будет равен K;
- каждое увеличение счетчика будет приравниваться переменной Number для вычисления самого "перевёртыша" во вложенном цикле.
- В случае, если "перевёртыш" является палиндромом, cчетчик countFlip увеличивается.

При запуске программы, что бы я не вводил, программа выдаёт "1". Почему?

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Потому что вы не умеете отлаживать программы. Если бы элементарно выводили на экран значение flip в каждой итерации, то обнаружили бы причину ошибки в две секунды.

Comment: @Эникейщик Ну это ещё надо догадаться, какую переменную на экран выводить ))  Но так то да, можно напечатать все.

Comment: @CrazyElf да чего догадываться, тут всего две интересующих переменных - countNumber и flip :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное потому, что `flip` надо инициализировать там же где `Number` - перед циклом проверки:

```
K = int(input())
countNumber = 0
countFlip = 0
for countNumber in range(1, K+1):
    Number = countNumber
    flip = 0 # нужно инициализировать здесь
    while Number > 0:
        flip = flip * 10 + Number % 10
        Number = Number // 10
    if countNumber == flip:
       countFlip += 1
print(countFlip)
```

У вас просто переменная `flip` не сбрасывалась, а копилась дальше и, естественно, она уже не проходила проверку на равенство `countNumber` на итерациях дальше первой.

P.S. Я ещё немного код сократил, а то были и лишние переменные и лишняя инициализация, и цикл можно же короче написать.